# How to truncate text on html page

Tags: html, css

I have some text on four columns side-by-side that I want to truncate to be equal.

What I need is to truncate text on 50 symbols for example so I to make all columns equals height.

I found one solution but it doesn't go well since the HTML is bootstrap and text go one over another

```
.feature_content p {
width: 200px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Look in to dotdotdot - https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.dotdotdot I've used it before when I needed elements to all be the same height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dotdotdot??  The same thing can be done with 5 lines of JS/JQUERY.  Answer is below with JSFiddle link.

JSFiddle Link:  http://jsfiddle.net/q8v2kywn/

**The JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".column").each(function() {
    var theContent = $(this).html();
    var how_short_you_want_it = theContent.substr(0, 150);
    //alert(how_short_you_want_it);
    $(this).html(how_short_you_want_it+'...');
});//close each function

});
```

**The CSS**

```
.column{
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    width:20%;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div class="column">put your text here</div>
<div class="column">put your text here</div>
<div class="column">put your text here</div>
<div class="column">put your text here</div>
```

Comment: DotDotDot is far more advanced than you're giving it credit for. Look at the demos here: http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/. And it can be applied with one line of JQuery.

Comment: um. ok. so?  they didn't need that?  That wasn't the question. Also the question said they already had issues with scripts stomping on each other, so...  easiest solution wins.